# There's something about AMD ATI Graphics

Tags: ati, graphics

I'm pretty sure that you have encountered many of these related issue topic.
But I just want to get my curiosity untangled.

I have followed the steps to install ATI drivers based on section 2.1 in [BinaryDriverHowto/ATI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

It all seems fine (based on the link revision) with my fglrxinfo result output:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11903 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Performance doesn't differ much from the default open source that I've previously used but, when i check my system info. It says that my graphic is

```
Graphics: VESA:WRESTLER
```

Which is the same value displayed when I was using the default open source before.

Q: So my question is. Is this result expected and my driver is actually properly installed?

Q: And if possible of explanation, why?

Laptop info: [Asus K43U](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K43U/#specifications)